# Outlook x-headers for automatically flagging/categorising email

Tags: email, outlook

I'm creating a website for a client that has a form which will sent emails to a centralised inbox. They have stressed the importance that website emails are quickly dealt with as they could be new business leads. For this reason they'd like they to be clearly flagged.

The simple option is to prefix the subject with some wording. Perhaps make a message rule to do something with this email but I was wondering if I can be clever and include a custom x-header that tells Outlook to automatically assign is to one of the coloured categories or adds a follow up flag. Is this possible or am I stuck with message rules added by the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible so I've just used the priority header instead. This is using the [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) API php wrapper. It's not ideal, but for this client it works as they want to emails clearly marked. 1 = highest, 3 = normal, 5 = lowest, 2 and 4 are in between values but not commonly used.

```
'headers' => array(
    'X-Priority' => 1
)
```